# Guardar cadena de caracteres en C

Tags: c, string

¿Cómo podría leer por teclado una cadena de caracteres y almacenarla en una variable? La variable no debe tener un tamaño fijo. Me está costando un poco. Gracias!

Lo siento apenas tengo nada de código, todo lo que pruebo está mal. Estoy intentando hacerlo con un malloc pero no hay manera :(

Comment: Hola, que haz intentado hacer? Puedes dejar el codigo?

Comment: Hola yo manejo las cadenas, como me explicaron en esta pagina, espero que te ayude. [Cadenas de texto (strings)](http://platea.pntic.mec.es/vgonzale/cyr_0204/cyr_01/control/lengua_C/cadenas.htm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ¿Cómo podría leer por teclado una cadena de caracteres y almacenarla en una variable?

Para leer un valor desde el teclado puede usarse [`scanf`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). A esta función le debes indicar el formato de los datos que quieres leer y la dirección de la variable en que quieres leerlos, veámoslo en un ejemplo:

```
int numero = 0;
scanf("%d", &numero);
```

El `"%d"` indica que pretendes leer un número, si quisieras leer una cadena de caracteres deberías usar `"%s"`:

```
char cadena_de_caracteres[100];
scanf("%s", cadena_de_caracteres);
```

Aquí no usamos el operador dirección-de ([el et `&`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%26)) porque el nombre del arreglo *equivale* a la dirección del primer elemento del mismo. Hay que tener en cuenta que leer `"%s"` añade el [carácter de control](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car%C3%A1cter_de_control) de final de cadena: [el carácter nulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character).

> La variable no debe tener un tamaño fijo.

Si no es tamaño fijo: es tamaño variable. Para ello deberás averiguar primero el tamaño de la cadena que quieres leer y seguidamente leer la cadena:

```
int longitud_de_la_cadena = 0;
printf("Longitud de la cadena: ");
scanf("%d", &longitud_de_la_cadena);

char *cadena = (char *)malloc(longitud_de_la_cadena + 1);
printf("Cadena: ");
scanf("%s", cadena);

printf("\"%s\" es la cadena de %d caracteres introducida.\n", cadena, longitud_de_la_cadena);
```

El código anterior introduciendo los valores `6` y `patata` muestra:

> ```
> Longitud de la cadena: 6
> Cadena: patata
> "patata" es la cadena de 6 caracteres introducida.
> ```

Aquí usamos [`malloc`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) para alojar el tamaño que necesitamos para nuestra cadena de longitud variable, no debemos olvidar liberar la memoria solicitada antes de acabar el programa usando la función [`free`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free):

```
free(cadena);
```

Comment: `scanf("%<len>s", &var);` Evitaría muchos inconvenientes con el `stdout/printf` escupiendo *garbage.* _***cof, cof***_ ¿O no?

Comment: ¿Pero `"%<len>s"`no funciona sólo con `printf`?

Comment: **EDIT:** En ambos es posible, añadiendo el especificador de la siguiente forma: `"%.<len>s"`, typos por todas partes.

Comment: No lo veo en ningún lado de la documentación de `scanf` esta funcionalidad (San Google me aconseja usar `fgets` si quiero especificar la longitud de aquello que quiera leer) ¿puede ser una extensión de compilador?

Comment: No hice la prueba completa, pero al parecer funciona :P, lo leí en un lado en SO, [mirá](http://ideone.com/MzlIzk), tambien creo que sólo funciona de c99+

Comment: El [código que me has pasado](http://ideone.com/MzlIzk) no parece funcionar de la manera esperada, me indica que no hay salida: `Standard output is empty` pese al `printf` del final.

Comment: No la dará, porque no hemos pedido nada desde `stdin`, se pide en tiempo de ejecución y creo que ideone no lo ejecuta de manera online...

Comment: Tienes algo en stdin según puedo ver, pero cambiando a Wandbox que sí acepta stdin: [no funciona](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ZF3YO5egrUgDJvaj), es más: indica que no reconoce el formato: `warning: unknown conversion type character '.' in format `.

Comment: +1 Tambien me da el error, al parecer me he confundido de función *(xD!)*

Answer (score 3):

Podría ser este siguiente ejemplo como ayuda a tu duda:

> Realizar un programa que permita a un usuario ingresar por teclado
>   varios datos que serán almacenados en un arreglo (array) de cadenas
>   (strings). El programa al inicio debe pedir la cantidad y el tamaño de
>   los datos a ingresar.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,cant,tam;

    printf("Ingresar una cantidad de datos: ");
    scanf("%d",&cant);
    printf("Ingresar el tamanio: ");
    scanf("%d",&tam);

    char *arreglo[cant];
    char* dato;

    for(i=0; i<cant; i++){
        printf("Ingresar dato %i: ",i);
        dato = (char*) malloc(tam);
        scanf("%s",dato);
        arreglo[i] = dato;
    }

    printf("\nLos datos ingresados son: \n");
    for(i=0; i<cant; i++){
        printf("=>%s\n",arreglo[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Espero esto te pueda ayudar, saludos.

Comment: Gracias, estaba buscando algo así. ¿Sabes si hay alguna forma para que el tamaño del malloc se ajuste a lo que escribas por teclado sin tener que especificarlo? Gracias!

Comment: Esta respuesta está mal. No se puede declarar una variable durante la ejecución del programa. El espacio ocupado en memoria por 'arreglo' dependera del valor que haya ingresado el usuario para la variable cant. Probablemente ese código ni siquiera compile. Lo que necesitas usar es memoria dinámica y la única manera de hacer eso en C es usando la función malloc.

Comment: @cventu en el estándar C99 está permitido crear arreglos de longitud variable siempre y cuando estos no esten en espacio global, así que en este caso `char *arreglo[cant]` sería válido (en C99). Por otro lado el soporte a arreglos de tamaño variable se hizo opcional a partir del estándar C11 por lo que en ese estándar el soporte a esta funcionalidad dependerá del compilador.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Gracias, no sabía que C99 permitía hacer eso. Sin embargo sería un error acostumbrarse a programar de esa manera, ya que si el usuario ingresa una cantidad de datos (bytes en este caso) mayor al espacio disponible en memoria, se produciría un error durante la ejecución del programa y el mismo se frenaría completamente. En cambio al usar malloc se puede chequear el valor de retorno de la función para saber sino se pudo alocar memoria.

Comment: @cventu el consenso general con los ALV era que son una benigna alternativa a `alloca` si se usaban con conocimiento y para arreglos de tamaño pequeño; no tengo claro los motivos técnicos e históricos que llevaron a dejar de pensar así pero sea como sea, ceñirse al estándar suele ser la opción que menos problemas da.

Answer (score 2):

Te han puesto varios ejemplos en los que hay que indicar el tamaño... aquí va un enfoque diferente:

```
int main()
{
  printf("Introduce una cadena:\n");

  char* ptr = 0;
  int ptrSize = 0;

  while( 1 )
  {
    ptr = (char*)realloc(ptr,ptrSize + 1);
    int c = getchar();
    if( c == EOF )
    {
      ptr[ptrSize] = 0;
      break;
    }
    ptr[ptrSize] = (char)c;
    ptrSize++;
  }

  printf("Cadena introducida:\n%s",ptr);
  free(ptr);
}
```

En este caso la memoria donde se almacena la cadena se va redimensionando conforme se introducen caracteres... de tal forma que no es necesario indicar previamente cuantos caracteres se van a introducir